# Image with large file size not cropping

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, cropping

I just set hard crop in function 676x429 hard crop.

```
add_image_size('home-slide', 676, 429, true);
```

Its working but client uploaded a large file something like 3800x3800 (5.73mb) and it doesn't crop. But when I reduce the size by 1600x1600 and it works.

Why it doesn't cropping on large files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WordPress uses the GD Graphics Library to resize and crop images. On servers with limited resources however, [GD fails on images with large file sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272814/resize-images-too-large-for-gd-library-on-my-server).

If you really need to keep the size of your images, but want to keep your file sizes down, consider processing your images first with [tinypng.com](https://tinypng.com/). Their online compressor retains as much quality as possible, processes up to 20 files at a time, and is free.